# Firebase database updates same value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to database and firebase, I have been working on updating the firebase database. But when I update the firebase it only updates the first value without changing other value.

This is the part of the editMenu from which display the menu and has the option to edit and delete menu.

```
contentMenuKeys.map(t=>{
              // if (t === this.state.Appetizer)

              return(
                <div className="text-center">
                  <h4>{t}</h4>

                  <div className="row">
                    {Object.keys(this.props.menu[t]).map(menu=>{
                      return(

                      [this.props.menu[t][menu]].map(item=>{
                        return(
                          <div className="col-md-6 menuItems" >
                            <div className="textM d-flex">
                              <div className="one-half">
                                <h3>{item.Name}</h3>
                                <p><span>{item.Description}</span></p>

                              </div>
                              <div className="one-forth">
                                <span className="price">${item.Price}</span>
                                <p><span>
                                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#MenuEditModal">Edit</button ><MenuEditForm Menu_Type={t} Name={item.Name}Description={item.Description}  Price={item.Price}iID={menu} rID={queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).id }/>{"   "}
                                  <button  type="submit" onClick={()=>{this.props.deleteMenu({rID:queryString.parse(this.props.location.search).id,Menu_Type:t,iID:menu})}} className="btn btn-danger ml-2">Remove</button>
                                </span></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        )
```

And menuEditform component which has form for editing Menu

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from "react-redux"
import propTypes from "prop-types"
import { editMenu } from "../../actions/addMenu"



export class MenuEditForm extends Component {
    state={
        Name:"",
        Description: "",
        Price:"",
        Menu_Type:"",
        rID:""
    }

    static propTypes={
        editMenu: propTypes.func.isRequired

    }


    onChange=e=> this.setState({[e.target.name]:e.target.value});


    onSubmit=e=>{

        e.preventDefault();

        const { Name, Description, Price, rID, Menu_Type } = this.state;
        const menu = { Name, Description, Price, Menu_Type, rID, iID:this.props.iID };

        this.props.editMenu(menu);
        this.setState({
            Name:"",
            Description: "",
            Price:"",
            Menu_Type:"",
        });

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({rID:this.props.rID,iID:this.props.iID,Menu_Type:this.props.Menu_Type})
      }


    render(){
        const {Name, Description, Price, Menu_Type}=this.state;
```

And this is the editMenu Function

```
export const editMenu =(item) =>(dispatch)=>{
    axios
        .post("/api/database/editMenu", item)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type:EDIT_MENU,
                payload:res.data

            });
        })
        .catch(err=>
            dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.date,err.response.status)));


};
```

And this is the firebase Part

```
def editMenu(request):   
    db=credentials().database()
    mType = request['Menu_Type']
    rID=request['rID']
    iID =request['iID']
    print(request)
    request.pop("Menu_Type")
    request.pop('rID')
    request.pop('iID')




    return db.child('Restaurants').child(rID).child("Menu").child(mType).child(iID).update(request)
```

Comment: It's quite hard to understand what is happening in your code. Can you reproduce the problem without using ReactJS? Possibly without the HTML? Having less code to consider, makes it more likely that someone will see what's going wrong. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you see the editMenu part where I have used a loop to get the item details and then redirected to MenuEdit form. When I edit the menu, It only changes the first value in the list in the database. I could not edit the desired menu @FrankvanPuffelen